# DJango form with custom __init__ not validating

Tags: django, forms

When I use this code to customize my form's widget, it will not validate.  If I comment out `def __init__(..)` it works fine.

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.wysiwyg = kwargs.pop('wysiwyg', False)

        super(CommentForm, self).__init__()
        if self.wysiwyg:
            self.fields['comment_text'].widget = SummernoteWidget()
        else:
            self.fields['comment_text'].widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':2})

    comment_text = forms.CharField()
```

I've been able to troubleshoot this far, and the difference between the working form (no **init**) and the invalid form, is this:

not valid form with **init**:

```
CommentForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(comment_text)
```

valid form:

```
CommentForm bound=True, valid=Unknown, fields=(comment_text)
```

Is bound the problem and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: One minor note- you are not sending the args, and kwargs into the super

Comment: It's not minor, it's major. When you're not passing args and kwargs into __init__ from super, form won't receive POST data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this .. might work

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        self.wysiwyg = kwargs['wysiwyg']
    except KeyError:
        self.wysiwyg = None

    super(CommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.wysiwyg:
        self.fields['comment_text'].widget = SummernoteWidget()
    else:
        self.fields['comment_text'].widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':2})

comment_text = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: Trying your code, I am getting this error:
`__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wysiwyg'`
This is how the form is begin created:
`comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, wysiwyg=True)`

Comment: using your code, if I pop the keyword: `self.wysiwyg = kwargs.pop('wysiwyg', False)` I don't get any errors.  I think this is working!