# django custom form is invalid due to form init

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following form:

```
class PlayerAchievementForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PlayerAchievement
        fields = ('achievement',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlayerAchievementForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fields['achievement'].queryset = Achievement.objects.filter(input_type=0)
```

I have the following implementation in a view:

```
def points(request, action, target=None):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if target == 'player':
            form = PlayerAchievementForm(request.POST)
            print form.errors
            if form.is_valid():
                print 'valid'
            elif:
                print 'invalid'
```

On submit, this prints invalid.

If I take out this line in the form:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(PlayerAchievementForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.fields['achievement'].queryset = Achievement.objects.filter(input_type=0)
```

Then it saves without issue.  What is wrong with the init?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:  [DJango form with custom __init__ not validating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129579/django-form-with-custom-init-not-validating)

I was missing:

```
super(PlayerAchievementForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after a lot of tries, the code that work for me is something like that:

(Notice the first instantiation of the the field at class level.)

```
class PlayerAchievementForm(forms.ModelForm):

    achievement = Achievement.objects.filter(input_type=0)

    class Meta:
        model = PlayerAchievement
        fields = ('achievement',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlayerAchievementForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fields['achievement'].queryset = Achievement.objects.filter(input_type=0)
```